# Using has function for sampling large data set

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

So far I have been sampling large files using the following approach:

```
with open(myfile) as f1:
    with open(output,'w') as f2:
        for i,line in enumerate(f1):
            if i%my_rate==0:
                f2.write(line)
```

This code iterates through the input file and takes every n (=my_rate) samples and writes them into an output file.

How can I improve this approach? I am thinking to use a hash function that will sample 20% of the input data based on the key (in my case that's UserID).

I am using Spark, so everything can fit into memory. While looking around I found out about MurmurHash3, but I don't know a lot about Python hashing functions and I just started using Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to randomly sample, you could use the `random` package to draw a random number and only use the line if the draw below a certain value.

```
import random
cutoff = .2 # (random draws between 0 and 1, so .2 would yield a 20% sample.)
with open(myfile) as f1:
    with open(output,'w') as f2:
        for i,line in enumerate(f1):
            if random.random() < cutoff:
                f2.write(line)
```

Comment: Hi! I want to take 20% of each customerID and I want to use a hash function approach. Something like https://bzhangusc.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/sample-by-a-hash-function/

Comment: Why do you want to use a hash function?

Comment: I want to draw "random" sample based on CustomerID. So it's not really a random function. I need 20% of each CustomerID. In my opinion, hash function is the best approach

Comment: If you need 20% of each customer ID then, within each customer only take 20% of their content based on a pseudo-random number generator (the example above would get 20% each in expectation, you could also generate a random order and only take the first 20% to get exactly 20% from each user). If you hash their openID it will be the same every time, so I really don't understand how you would do the within user randomization with a hash function of their openID.

Comment: Also, it's not really a random sample is the scariest thing I consistently here from CS folks. Not doing randomization correctly breaks sampling properties, makes it difficult to generalize, and easy to screw up.

Comment: Finally, note that what you are describing (20% sample from each user) will place greater weight on users with more lines/content and is extremely close to just taking a 20% random sample of lines. Probably better to sample n lines from each user (stratified random sample) so that each user has equal weight in a subsequent model.

Comment: The point is that I don't know how many samples each user will have

Comment: You could sample with replacement, such that even if a user only has 4 lines you could sample 5 from each user. You could also drop these people if you know substantively that you're not interested in extremely infrequent users.

Comment: One particular problem that may arise using just random is how to replicate the sampling. Assume you did not store if a piece of content was sampled or not, and now you can re do your sample. If using a hash funcion, or using the id as a seed, maybe you can reproduce the same sampling previously done. Is that possible?